# impala Unregister query to long time

Tags: php, database, impala

Our company is now using CDH 5.10 and Impala 2.7 version as the background of their own data, recently found a headache.

Some query **Unregister query** accounted for more than 60% of the query time, but I put the same SQL copy into the impala-shell implementation time much less, less time is probably Unregister query time.

Can you help me doubts?  Are there are ways to improve it? 
There are screenshots nearby. [image]

Answer (score 0):

To quote https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2355:

> this timer keeps track of how much time passes from when the first result row is available and when the client has called the fetch RPC to retrieve the results. So, for some reason it appears that your client is not calling fetch timely. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go back and check it out

Comment: Thats not correct.. On jira the engineer was actually explaining the meaning for client fetch timer and not unregister query.